# How to reset/restart an internal Macbook trackpad driver?

Tags: macos, drivers, macbook, touchpad

[My Macbook's trackpad occasionally starts behaving erratically](https://superuser.com/questions/301203/macbook-air-trackpad-not-clicking-nor-moving-cursor-but-multi-finger-gestures-ar) but after a system restart it works well again (at least for a while).

I'm still looking for a solution to the root problem of the errors.

However, for now, is there some way to restart just the trackpad's driver instead of the whole system to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 19):

Find the terminal app then enter this:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: This has happened to many times before. This needs more upvotes. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: But can you reboot the trackpad without having to restart the computer?

Comment: Yep, that’s what that command does.

Comment: I got MacBook Air 2020 and recently, i got this weird trackpad where the cursor will only move within a section of the screen, like hitting some invisible bound. I don’t want to reboot every time this happens, this command doesnt help me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases that I have seen with trackpads not acting as expected it is hardware, not the drivers. The easiest way to test this (depending on how easy it is to reproduce) is to boot to a known good operating system; i.e.: a different partition containing the OS either one you made or the recovery partition by holding down option and selecting Recovery HD (10.7 and newer). IF it happens there because the recovery partition or triage partition (one that you created) then you KNOW it is hardware. In which case if it is internal, I would say take it to someone to adjust it/replace it... ESPECIALLY if it is a MacBook Air.(They have exposed batteries, when mishandled can cause damage) It is most likely one of a few situations A) Battery needs to be replaced, old batteries expand (it's intended that way) and can cause the issue. B) Debris is in the cracks of the trackpad C) Liquid damage, more cases than not, users cause their own issues D) The trackpad breaks on it's own. Seen this very few times. In which case, you need a new trackpad. Go to locate.apple.com to find someone that is trained to take these units apart, in most cases Apple can reseat a trackpad and if needed, replace it at a cost if not under AppleCare or there is physical damage.

Answer (score 0):

As per first answer, try running the following commands in Terminal:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.Dock.agent
```

in order to force a stop and restart the Finder and Dock. Be aware it'll re-open all your windows.

Alternatively you need to reset [the System Management Controller (SMC)](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295).

---

If your mouse still behaves in unexpected manner, see:

- [Mouse pointer on my MacBook moves by itself](https://superuser.com/q/383640/87805).
- [Macbook Air trackpad not clicking nor moving cursor, but multi-finger gestures are working](https://superuser.com/q/301203/87805)